# How to document software algorithms?

Tags: modeling

I'm working on a large project for a university assignment, we're developing an application that is used by a business to compile quotes for their various services.

I need to document the algorithms in a way that the client can sign off on to make sure the way we calculate the prices is correct

So far I've tried using a large flow chart with decisions diamonds like in information systems modelling but it's proving to be overkill for even simple algorithms.

Can anybody please suggest some ways to do this? It needs to be as little like software code as possible, and enough for the client to see how we decide what prices are quoted

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should then use pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

Create two documents.

- **First:** The business process model [(BPM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BPMN-AProcesswithNormalFlow.svg) that shows the sequence of steps required to be done. This should be annotated with the details for each step.
- **Second:**  Create a spreadsheet with each input data item defined so that business can see that you understand the type of field for entry of each data point and the rules for each data point.  If the calculation uses a table for the step, then that is where you define the input lookup value from the table.  So for each step you know where the data is coming from and then going to.  Your spreadsheet can include the link to the BPM so they can walk through each data point in the BPM and see where it is coming from/going to.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare screen designs to show the users how your system is doing actually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the usual way to document algorithms is writing papers.
If your clients have studied business, I'm sure they are familiar with reading formulas.

Comment: How come this is the adequate solution if the OP is saying even *flowcharts are overkill*?

Answer (score 0):

Would a [data flow diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram) help? Put psuedo code or math in the bubbles. I've had some success combining data flow models and entity relationship diagrams, but it's non standard.

Answer (score 0):

What about Nassi-Shneiderman-Diagram, it's a diagram from structural programming. I think its good to show decision flows.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassi%E2%80%93Shneiderman_diagram

Answer (score 0):

You could create an algorithm test screen to display and comment on the various steps through the calculations.